# How to get the text that is not wrapped of any element and put it in p element

Tags: jquery

How can I get the text in this markup?

```
<div itemprop="description">
  <p>Testing article....</p>
  <div class="inline-image inline_image_240x240">
    <img alt="" title="" src="http://kite.dev.cnngo.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/inline_image_240x240/2012/06/27/600x600_5.png">
    <div class="in-captioninline_image_240x240"></div>
  </div>
  I want this to put inside the blank <p> element below.
  <p></p>
  <p>Another p.....</p>
</div>
```

I want to be like this.

```
<div itemprop="description">
  <p>Testing article....</p>
  <div class="inline-image inline_image_240x240">
    <img alt="" title="" src="http://kite.dev.cnngo.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/inline_image_240x240/2012/06/27/600x600_5.png">
    <div class="in-captioninline_image_240x240"></div>
  </div>
  <p>I want this to put inside the blank <p> element below.</p>
  <p>Another p.....</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: Sorry I just edited my post. Thanks

Comment: For some reason when adding image the paragraph gets broken.

Comment: @ninjascorner why not wrap it in a span and use appendTo() ?

Comment: @ninjascorner Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/2U4Hb/1/ . This will remove that empty `p` and wrap that `text` inside `p`. Check in the console the final html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## **Complete Edit:**

I see. ​You won't be able to move just plain text into that "P" tag so you will need to rap it in another P with a class/id. In this case i'll give it a class. You also can't just have a random "

" in there. This would break the html. So I just changed that to: "<p>" so it would turn into text instead of interfearing with the HTML

Change your HTML to this:

```
<div itemprop="description">
  <p>Testing article....</p>
  <div class="inline-image inline_image_240x240">
    <img alt="" title="" src="http://kite.dev.cnngo.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/inline_image_240x240/2012/06/27/600x600_5.png">
    <div class="in-captioninline_image_240x240"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="p">I want this to put inside the blank &lt;p> element below.</p>
  <p></p>
  <p>Another p.....</p>
</div>
```

You can move that to the next P using [.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next):

```
var el = $('div[itemprop="description"]').find('.p');
el.next().text(el.text()).prev().remove();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shawn31313/R5B6j/)

Comment: Hi Shawn...this may not solved my problem how ever I have a multiple inline images in my content in different position.

Comment: I found out that by default the browser doesn't allow this kind of structure:

`<p>
  <div>
    <img>
  </div>
</p>`

Comment: Have you tried: `<p> <div> <img /> </div> </p>`. That would be the valid way to do it.

Comment: Check me edit, I really hope this is what you are looking for!

Comment: No, that's not valid. `<p>` can only contain text or inline elements, not other block elements like `<div>`. If you need a generic container inside a `<p>`, use `<span>` since it's an inline element and therefore allowable.

Comment: Um, there will be only text in it. WOW

Comment: Thanks guys...seems its impossible to put div inside the p tag

Comment: THats what you want? Yes that would be possible but you question is not clear at all.